# Excel VB: How to convert multiple 'for' + 'if' loops to 'for each' cell + 'for' loop

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement, foreach

[Update Below]
Im getting to grasp the basics of VBA and have automated a few things, however, I think I can step up my game, hence I have a question.

I have a Excel workbook where on one sheet ('Source') I update a number of bank balances on a daily basis using a power query. On a second sheet ('ThisWeek') I combine all the bank balances for the entire week.

Data looks as follows:
Source:

```
|---------------------|------------------|--------------------|------------------|
|      Account Code   | Entity Code      | Balance Yesterday  | Balance Today    |
|---------------------|------------------|--------------------|------------------|
|       Account 1     |  Account Holder  |    Value 1         |    Value 2       |
|---------------------|------------------|--------------------|------------------|
```

ThisWeek

```
|  Monday             | 
|---------------------|------------------|--------------------|------------------|
|      Account Code   | Entity Code      | Date    Yesterday  | Date Today       |
|---------------------|------------------|--------------------|------------------|
|       Account 1     |    Account name  |*Insert value 1 here| and Value 2 here |
|---------------------|------------------|--------------------|------------------|
|Tuesday              |
|---------------------|------------------|--------------------|------------------|
|      Account Code   | Entity Code      | Date    Yesterday  | Date Today       |
|---------------------|------------------|--------------------|------------------|
|       Account 1     |    Account name  |*Insert value 1 here| and Value 2 here |
|---------------------|------------------|--------------------|------------------|
```

In the end I want the macro to copy the daily balances from the source sheet and paste them on the correct day in my weekly overview. **i'm not yet looking at pasting at the right date (i.e. daily balances from Wednesday to the Wednesday part in 'ThisWeek', that will come into play later**

The common denominator on both sheets is "Account 1", "Account 2" etc. etc.

I now have the below lines of code for each account, which works fine, but I have as much blocks of codes as I have bank accounts. Also not sure if I have to activate the Sheets every time or if this can be simplified as well.
A few notes:
LastRow = the last row in the 'Source' sheet with a bank balance. Furthermore I now created multiple variables for each bank account (i.e. variable = Account 1). The 'Balance' variable captures the 'Value 1' and 'Value 2' (bank balances of specific account in each loop).

the 'j' at the moment just looks at the first day of my weekly table as I haven't figured out how to make it refer to today's date and compare that to related part in 'ThisWeek'

```
 Source.Activate

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = Account 1 Then
            Set Balance = Range("C" & i, "D" & i)
            ThisWeek.Activate
                For j = 4 To 26
                
                    If Cells(j, 1).Value = Account 1 Then
                        Range("C" & j, "D" & j) = Balance.Value
                    End If

                Next j
                    
        End If
    
    Next i
```

I was thinking I could set a range in ThisWeek which would capture all the relevant accounts (Source contains more balances than I'm interested in) and do something like the below.
The advantage would be I don't have to declare all the individual accounts anymore and I would reduce the blocks of code.

```
Set Accounts = ThisWeek.Range("A2:A26")

For Each Cell In Accounts
    For i = 2 To LastRow

        If Cell.Value = Source.Cells(i, 1) Then
            Set Balance = Source.Range("C" & i, "D" & i)
            ThisWeek.Activate
                If Cell.Value = Source.Cells(i, 1) Then
                    ThisWeek.Range("C" & i, "D" & i) = Balance.Value
            End If
        End If
    Next i
Next
```

This does copy some balances to my 'ThisWeek' sheet, however, it does not paste them after the right account. (i.e. I get Account 1 with the Values of Account 7 of the 'Source' sheet).

Any help on how to align the rights balances with the right accounts?

Sorry for the long post.

Thanks in advance,
Thomas

[Update]
Seem to have almost found it, see below.
Only thing is that my variable 'Balance' should contain 2 values (i.e. yesterdays + todays balance from 'Source'). However, when offsetting the active Cell it only pastes 1 value?
How to you offset a 'Range' from a Cell? Is that possible? Or should I created another variable and Offset twice?

```
Sub ImportBalances()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim ThisWeek As Worksheet
    
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    
    Dim Balance As Range
    Dim Accounts As Range
    
    Dim Account As String
    
    Dim Today As Date
    Dim Monday As Date
    Dim Tuesday As Date
    Dim Wednesday As Date
    Dim Thursday As Date
    Dim Friday As Date
           
'Set workbook + worksheet
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set Source = Sheets("Balances from Buitend.htm")
    Set ThisWeek = Sheets("ThisWeek")
    
'Count number of rows with data in Source
    LastRow = Source.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Define days of the week
    With ThisWeek
'        Today = Date
        Today = DateValue("Jul 10, 2020") 'This is for testing
        Monday = Range("A2")
        Tuesday = Range("A30")
        Wednesday = Range("A58")
        Thursday = Range("A86")
        Friday = Range("A114")
    End With
   
'Copy balances
'Monday
    If Today = Monday Then
    Set Accounts = ThisWeek.Range("A4:A26") 'Refers to accounts listed in Column A under 'Monday' on 'ThisWeek'
        For Each Cell In Accounts
            Account = Cell.Value
            
            For i = 2 To LastRow
                If Source.Cells(i, 1).Value = Account Then
                    Set Balance = Source.Range("C" & i, "D" & i)
                    Cell.Offset(0, 2) = Balance.Value
                End If
            Next i
        Next
'Tuesday
    ElseIf Today = Tuesday Then
    Set Accounts = ThisWeek.Range("A32:A54") 'Refers to accounts listed in Column A under 'Tuesday' on 'ThisWeek'
        For Each Cell In Accounts
            Account = Cell.Value
            
            For i = 2 To LastRow
                If Source.Cells(i, 1).Value = Account Then
                    Set Balance = Source.Range("C" & i, "D" & i)
                    Cell.Offset(0, 2) = Balance.Value
                End If
            Next i
        Next
'Wednesday
    ElseIf Today = Wednesday Then
    Set Accounts = ThisWeek.Range("A60:A82") 'Refers to accounts listed in Column A under 'Wednesday' on 'ThisWeek'
        For Each Cell In Accounts
            Account = Cell.Value
            
            For i = 2 To LastRow
                If Source.Cells(i, 1).Value = Account Then
                    Set Balance = Source.Range("C" & i, "D" & i)
                    Cell.Offset(0, 2) = Balance.Value
                End If
            Next i
        Next
'Thursday
    ElseIf Today = Thursday Then
    Set Accounts = ThisWeek.Range("A88:A110") 'Refers to accounts listed in Column A under 'Thursday' on 'ThisWeek'
        For Each Cell In Accounts
            Account = Cell.Value
            
            For i = 2 To LastRow
                If Source.Cells(i, 1).Value = Account Then
                    Set Balance = Source.Range("C" & i, "D" & i)
                    Cell.Offset(0, 2) = Balance.Value
                End If
            Next i
        Next
    
    ElseIf Today = Friday Then
    Set Accounts = ThisWeek.Range("A116:A138") 'Refers to accounts listed in Column A under 'Friday' on 'ThisWeek'
        For Each Cell In Accounts
            Account = Cell.Value
            
            For i = 2 To LastRow
                If Source.Cells(i, 1).Value = Account Then
                    Set Balance = Source.Range("C" & i, "D" & i)
                    Cell.Offset(0, 2) = Balance.Value
                End If
            Next i
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What column and row indices are used for each sheet? For example, in your sheet Source, is "Account Code" in A1, "Entity Code" in B1, and so forth?

Comment: The Source sheet has headers in row 1, as depicted in the table. Actual data starts from row 2 until row 24 at the moment (but this might increase/decrease in the future). A fairly simple table (just the 4 columns (A-D), 1 header row and 23 rows of data). 

The ThisWeek sheet has some more formatting where 19 accounts are sorted geographically (info is not in the data) and depicted per day. Not a continuous table. 
That being said, account 1 etc is also in column A and Value 1 and Value 2 are also in column C and D (as in Source).